# Scala- creating a map from string

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Hi have a string and the if format of the string is mentioned below:

```
val str = "{a=10, b=20, c=30}"
```

All the parameters inside this string is unique and separated by comma and space.  Also This string always starts with '{' and ends with '}'. I want to create a Map out of this string something like below:

```
val values = Map("a" -> 10, "b" -> 20, "c" -> 30)
```

What is the most efficient way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

```
scala> val str = "{a=10, b=20, c=30}"
str: String = {a=10, b=20, c=30}

scala> val P = """.*(\w+)=(\d+).*""".r
P: scala.util.matching.Regex = .*(\w+)=(\d+).*

scala> str.split(',').map{ case P(k, v) => (k, v.toInt) }.toMap
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 10, b -> 20, c -> 30)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **regex** can simply achieve this:

```
  "(\\w+)=(\\w+)".r.findAllIn("{a=10, b=20, c=30}").matchData.map(i => {
    (i.group(1), i.group(2))
  }).toMap
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you want to write is pretty easy:

```
def convert(str : String) : Map[String, String] = {
    str.drop(1).dropRight(1).split(", ").map(_.split("=")).map(arr => arr(0)->arr(1)).toMap
}
```

with `drop` and `dropRight`, you remove the brackets. Then you split the String with the expression `,`, which results in multiple Strings.

Than you split each of this strings, which results in arrays with two elements. Those are used to create a map.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it likes this (I think regex is not needed here):

```
val str = "{a=10, b=20, c=30}"

val values: Map[String, Int] = str.drop(1).dropRight(1) // drop braces
  .split(",") // split into key-value pairs
  .map { pair =>
  val Array(k, v) = pair.split("=") // split key-value pair and parse to Int
  (k.trim -> v.toInt)
}.toMap
```